# JavaScript Array Map returns empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to have a upload mechanism which uploads pictures and turns them into base64 strings and then save them to a state. After that, I want to map in in a component. But it turns out, that `Array.map()` returns a empty array in this situation. Does array.map has a limitation?

```js
class TestFileInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
        super(props);
    this.fileToBase64 = this.fileToBase64.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        examplePictures: undefined
    }
  }
  fileToBase64(files){
        let array = [];

        for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            let reader = new FileReader();
            let file = files[i];
            reader.onload = function(event) {
                // Push to array
                array.push(event.target.result)
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
        //return array
        return array;
 }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.examplePictures);
    return (
        <div>
          <input type="file" multiple onChange={(e) => {
            this.setState({
            examplePictures: this.fileToBase64(e.target.files)
          })
        }}/>
        {this.state.examplePictures !== undefined ? (
            <div>
              {this.state.examplePictures.map(pic => (
                <img src={pic} alt=""/>
                ))}
            </div>
        ):""}

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So basically, when you upload pictures. The `fileToBase64` is getting called, returns an array (which works) with base64 strings. They get saved to the state (which works too). Only the mapping returns a empty array.

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/op69hbxm/3/

Comment: `array` will be `[]`, because you haven't chained the onLoad event. `push` will happen later after returning `array`

Comment: But the state has the values it needs, so the push event works. And I have `reader.onload` in there.

Comment: Try logging examplePictures, then mapping...`{console.log(this.state.examplePictures);this.state.examplePictures.map()}`. `push` works, but only after returning a empty array.

Comment: Yeah if I log it, examplepictures has the values it should have with the base64 strings. But if I map it, it just returns that empty array.

Comment: Where exactly? The first is for the callback and the second is for the map function

Comment: Okay, if I just log examplePictures I get the real array. But if I log the length of examplePictures I get 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed the fact the `FileReader` performs an async operation.
When you add `exemplePictures` to the state, the files are not done being converted.

I set up a codesandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-merkle-3qmwg) that, I guess, achieves what you want.

I did two things:

First, I promisify the `fileReader` to manipulate it more easily :

```
  readFileAsync = file => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = event => {
        resolve(event.target.result);
      };
      reader.onerror = reject;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  };
```

And I update the `fileToBase64` function to use the previous function and WAIT that every files are read before updating the state:

```
  async fileToBase64(files) {
    const examplePictures = await Promise.all(
      Array.from(files).map(this.readFileAsync)
    );
    this.setState({ examplePictures });
  }
```

The `Array.from(files)` is just here to convert the `FileList` to `Array` and therefore be able to map the list of files easily`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `onLoad` is asynchronous and somehow it's not adding to the state properly. I made a few modifications from your code where it's only add to the state after the image is loaded and also rendering only if it's have files

```
class TestFileInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
        super(props);

    this.state = {
        examplePictures: []
    }
  }
   chooseFiles = (e) => {
     const files = e.target.files;
     let reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = (event) => {
       this.setState((previousState) => ({
         examplePictures: [
           ...previousState.examplePictures,
           event.target.result,
         ]
       }));
     };

     for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
       let file = files[i];
       reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     }
   }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <input type="file" multiple onChange={this.chooseFiles}/>
        {this.state.examplePictures.length > 0 && (
            <div>
            {this.state.examplePictures.map(pic => (
                <img src={pic} alt=""/>
            ))}
            </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <TestFileInput />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x57aj9vt/28/